# How to scrape prices from an e-commerce site when their path change for offers in scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape this site:

My problem is that there are 2 type of prices in 2 different clases and the paths are different.

Normally I would do it with

```
item['price'] = sel.xpath('.//*[@class="price_discount"]/text()').extract_first()
```

But for this case I also need to scrape "atg_store_newPrice" that has the price when it has no offer in it.

Can I use a different selector and use it inside the price selector, inside the extract, something like

```
item['price'] = sel.xpath('.//*[@class="price_discount"]/text()').extract_first(default='sel.xpath('.//*[@class="atg_store_newPrice"]/text()').extract_first()')
```

Of course that gives invalid syntax, but maybe if I use a different selector I can do it? Like price2

```
item['price2'] = sel.xpath('.//*[@class="atg_store_newPrice"]/text()').extract_first()
```

Then

```
    item['price'] = sel.xpath('.//*[@class="price_discount"]/text()').extract_first(default='price2')
```

Pretty sure that's impossible too, so I want to ask for advise about how to solve this issue I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly your requirement, but you can use this XPath to cover both alternatives:

```
item['price'] = sel.xpath('(.//*[@class="price_discount"]|.//*[@class="atg_store_newPrice"])/text()').extract_first()
```